# How to correctly move CakePHP tree items up and and down?

Tags: cakephp, tree, cakephp-2.0

Im stuck with moving items of a tree up and down, the item is not being moved to the  correct position.

Please check these pictures:

https://docs.google.com/a/wgs.co.id/file/d/0B88jB6a4wxkTdTNtTGl1YjhXdTQ/edit?usp=drivesdk
[image]

https://docs.google.com/a/wgs.co.id/file/d/0B88jB6a4wxkTcW5pSFJyUnVhejA/edit?usp=drivesdk
[image]

My code for moving items is based on http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html#TreeBehavior::moveDown

Here is my code:

**Controller**

```
function admin_moveup($id = null, $delta = null) {
    $this->ProductNeed->id = $id;
    if (!$this->ProductNeed->exists()) {
       throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid id'));
    }

    if ($delta > 0) {
        $this->ProductNeed->moveUp($this->ProductNeed->id, abs($delta));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(
          'Silahkan tentukan posisi nomor order terlebih dahulu'
        );
    }

    return $this->redirect(array('admin' => true, 'controller' => $this->params['controller'], 'action' => 'index'));
}

function admin_movedown($id = null, $delta = null) {
    $this->ProductNeed->id = $id;
    if (!$this->ProductNeed->exists()) {
       throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid id'));
    }

    if ($delta > 0) {
        $this->ProductNeed->moveDown($this->ProductNeed->id, abs($delta));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(
          'Silahkan tentukan posisi nomor order terlebih dahulu'
        );
    }

    return $this->redirect(array('admin' => true, 'controller' => $this->params['controller'], 'action' => 'index'));
}
```

**View**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Order</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        if(!empty($data['rows'])) {
            $i = 0;
            foreach($data['rows'] as $key => $value) {
                $i++;
        ?>
        <tr id="row-<?php echo $i; ?>">
          <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>

                <td><?= $value ?></td>
                <td>
                  <?php
                  echo $this->Html->link(
                    'Up',
                    '/admin/'.$this->params['controller'].'/moveup/'.$key.'/'.$i
                  );
                  ?> 
                  <?php
                  echo $this->Html->link(
                    'Down',
                    '/admin/'.$this->params['controller'].'/movedown/'.$key.'/'.$i
                  );
                  ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <ul class="action">
                        <li><a href="<?= Router::url('/admin/'.$this->params['controller'].'/edit/'.$key, true) ?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ubah"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#deletemodal-<?= $i ?>" data-toggle="modal"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hapus"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <?= $html->modalBoxDelete($i, $key) ?>
                </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
            }
        } else {
            echo $html->noData(4);
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Re-read the docs that you've linked, the code takes a delta value, ie the numer of positions the item should be moved.

If you'd wanted to move an item by just one row, then you'll have to use a delta of `1`, your view template code however passes the items index in the array as the delta value, so for the **Kesehan Mata** row in your example that would be a `4`, hence the item is moved to after **Stamina Vitalitas**, which is `4` top level items ahead.

So either pass a static value of `1`, like

```
'/admin/'.$this->params['controller'].'/moveup/'.$key.'/1'

'/admin/'.$this->params['controller'].'/movedown/'.$key.'/1'
```

or if you don't plan to ever move the items by more than `1`, simply remove the delta argument alltogether and hardcode the value passed to `TreeBehavior::up/down()` in your controller methods.

Comment: Hi @ndm. OMG, yes you right "For example, if you’d like to move the “Sport” ( id of 3 ) category one position down, you would request: /categories/movedown/3/1." I really do not pay attention to the explanation below. Its work now :) Thank you so much! God Bless You.